# How to launch terminal and pass it a command programatically? | Swift3, macOS

Tags: macos, swift3, macos-sierra

So my code so far looks like this:

```
import Foundation
import AppKit

print("Starting")
let base = NSWorkspace()

print("Launching Terminal")
base.launchApplication("Terminal") //launches terminal

print("Terminating terminal")
let apps = base.runningApplications
for app in apps {

    if app.localizedName == "Terminal" {
        print(app.localizedName)

        app.terminate() //Terminate
        break
    }
}
```

I have figured out how to start terminal and then how to close it, but I don't know how to pass it a command.
The command I want to pass it is: "screencapture ~/Desktop/screenshot.jpg"

Comment: Why would you want to start a Terminal for this purpose? It should be possible to  execute /usr/sbin/screencapture directly via NSTask (or Process in Swift 3).

Comment: I taught about that but where does that save the screenshot what is the name of the file and in what file format?

Comment: Type "man screencapture" in the Terminal and you'll see all its command-line options, e.g. `/usr/bin/screencapture -t pdf destinationFile`.

Comment: But this is for the command if type it in terminal, but if I launch screencapture it runs and gives me the following text: "Last login: Sun Oct  2 14:45:19 on ttys002
Kristofs-iMac:~ kocsiskritsof$ /usr/sbin/screencapture ; exit;
screencapture: no file specified
logout
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]" After this I can't do anything but exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Martin suggested this executes `screencapture ~/Desktop/screenshot.jpg` in Swift 3

```
let fileURL = try! FileManager.default.url(for: .desktopDirectory, in: .userDomainMask, appropriateFor: nil, create: false)
Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/sbin/screencapture", arguments: [fileURL.appendingPathComponent("screenshot.jpg").path])
```

The way to get the URL to the desktop folder works only in non-sandboxed apps.

Comment: This works, thanks! Would you mind giving me a little bit of explanation of the code or point me to the proper documentation.

Comment: The first line retrieves the URL for the desktop of the user domain. The second line executes a shell task. Command- or  Option-click on the symbols to get the declaration / documentation.

Comment: And is it possible to capture all the monitors like if I pressed CMD+Shift+4 and two pictures would be saved to the desktop each with one of the desktops?

Comment: I guess, I'm not that familiar with `screencapture`, Read the man page and add further parameters to the `arguments` array.

Comment: Ok, so I found that the command to take a screenshot of the second window is: "screencapture files ~/Desktop/screenshot.jpg" 
So how do I add the "files" argument?
UPDATE: Nevermind I figured it out

Comment: `Process.launchedProcess(launchPath: "/usr/sbin/screencapture", arguments: ["files", fileURL.appendingPathComponent("screenshot.jpg").path])`